# Multiple item purchased but only being deducted to wallet once

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I have created a Laravel Application wherein items can be bought by points.
The problem is, whenever the user maliciously flooding the request, the transaction succeeds, the item has been inserted to ItemBank while the points was only deducted once.

This code is my initial version

```
$request->validate([
    'ProductNum',
    'g-recaptcha-response' => [
    'required',
        new reCaptcha
     ]
]);

$getItem = Shop::find($request->post('ProductNum'));

if($getItem){
    if($getItem->ItemLimited && $getItem->ItemStock <= 0){
        return _responseApi("$getItem->ItemName is out of stock");
    }

    if( $getItem->ItemSection == 1 ){
        if($getItem->ItemPrice > auth('api')->user()->ePoints)
            return _responseApi(0,"Not enough ".config('rancp.core.ePoints_Name')." to purchase this item");
            auth('api')->user()->ePoints -= $getItem->ItemPrice;
    }

    if( $getItem->ItemSection == 2 ){
        if($getItem->ItemPrice > auth('api')->user()->vPoints)
            return _responseApi(0,"Not enough vPoints to purchase this item");
            auth('api')->user()->vPoints -= $getItem->ItemPrice;
    }

    auth('api')->user()->save();

    $insertItemBank = ItemBank::create([
        'ProductNum' => $request->post('ProductNum'),
        'UserUID' => auth('api')->user()->UserName
    ]);

    if($insertItemBank->exists)
        return _responseApi(1,"You have successfully purchased $getItem->ItemName!");
}
```

When the initial version triggered the problem, i tried to use DB Transaction, but the problem still persists

```
\DB::transaction(function() use ($request) {

    $getItem = Shop::find($request->post('ProductNum'));

    if($getItem){

        if($getItem->ItemLimited && $getItem->ItemStock <= 0){
            return _responseApi("$getItem->ItemName is out of stock");
        }

        if( $getItem->ItemSection == 1 ){
            if($getItem->ItemPrice > auth('api')->user()->ePoints)
                return _responseApi(0,"Not enough ".config('rancp.core.ePoints_Name')." to purchase this item");
                auth('api')->user()->ePoints -= $getItem->ItemPrice;
        }

        if( $getItem->ItemSection == 2 ){
            if($getItem->ItemPrice > auth('api')->user()->vPoints)
                return _responseApi(0,"Not enough vPoints to purchase this item");
                auth('api')->user()->vPoints -= $getItem->ItemPrice;
        }

        auth('api')->user()->save();

        $insertItemBank = ItemBank::create([
            'ProductNum' => $request->post('ProductNum'),
            'UserUID' => auth('api')->user()->UserName
        ]);

        if($insertItemBank->exists)
            return _responseApi(1,"You have successfully purchased $getItem->ItemName!");
    }

    return _responseApi(0,"Failed to purchase item");

});
```

Comment: Usually best not to save cumulative (aggregate) data. Calculate balance from transaction records when needed.

Comment: You have a race condition. You check stock, points, etc before updating them. A second request placed quickly enough will query stock before an initial request has updated it, and will then go on to completion even though no stock remains. The answer is an atomic 'test and set' update. In SQL you might do `UPDATE stockitems SET stockremaining = stockremaining -1 WHERE stockremaining >0 AND stockid = 'ABC123'`, then check the number of affected rows to see if the update worked. If it did, you sold an item. I don't know how you'd do that in Laravel.

Comment: Hello @TangentiallyPerpendicular, i think my code above is checking the stocks properly, and also checks the point if it's greater than or equal to the item price.. the problem is if the user blatantly flood the request, the itembank create doubles, then the deduction happens only once

Comment: @June7 can you please elaborate more? thanks

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: @seiferxiii _"I think..."_ - you're wrong. You have a [race condition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). You haven't understood my comment.

Comment: Thanks @TangentiallyPerpendicular i see, it is indeed a race condition, i'll try to refactor my code once again. Thank you